# how can we Batch insert using java clickhouse-client?

Tags: java, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

Performance of `clickhouse-client` is far better than `clickhouse-jdbc` where we do have preparedStatment for batchInsert. But how can we do Batch insert using  `clickhouse-client`.

```
try (ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(preferredProtocol);
    ClickHouseResponse response = client.connect(server)
        .format(preferredFormat)
        .query("insert query")
        .params("param for insert query").execute().get()) {

    }
}
```

As http request is stateless and single but is there any other class or way to have batch insert OR we need to dynamically build insert query with multiple VALUES as parameters for query statement?

Answer (score 1):

For example https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-jdbc

```java
try (ClickHouseClient client = ClickHouseClient.newInstance(server.getProtocol())) {
    ClickHouseRequest<?> request = client.connect(server).format(ClickHouseFormat.RowBinaryWithNamesAndTypes);
    // load data into a table and wait until it's completed
    request.write().query("insert into my_table select c2, c3 from input('c1 UInt8, c2 String, c3 Int32')")
        .data(myInputStream).execute().thenAccept(response -> {
            response.close();
        });
```

You just need to implement `myInputStream`.

I have a question, what is the source of your data? Is it a file? Or stream of data in some format?

Comment: how you will provide params in it> in jdbc you can iterate over list and keep adding in ps.addBatch(obj);

Comment: Data source is List of Employees that need to store in table.